# Counting twin primes with a sieve-like algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, sieve-theory

The sequence [A002822](https://oeis.org/A002822), denoted as $S$, represents all the twin primes except $\{3, 5\}$. Other than that exception, $k$ and $k+2$ are twin primes iff $(k+1)/6\in S$. Let $S(N)$ be the subset of $S$ with elements less than or equal to $N$. An earlier discussion to compute all the elements of $S(N)$ can be found on MSE, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202350/full-set-of-congruences-uniquely-defining-all-twin-primes).

Now, let $f(\cdot)$ be a positive increasing function, made explicit later. Let $n$, with $1\leq n\leq N$, be a number satisfying the following: for some prime $p$ with $5\leq p\leq f(N)$,  we have $n\bmod{p}=\pm a_p$. Here $a_p=\lfloor(p+3)/6\rfloor$. Eliminate all those numbers from $\{1,\cdots,N\}$ and see what is left. The goal is to build a subset of $S(N)$, denoted as $S^*(N)$,  that is large enough, so that it hopefully contains infinitely many elements when $N=\infty$. By construction, all elements of $S(N)$ that are smaller than $f(n)/6$ will be missing in $S^*(N)$. The hope is that by choosing the function $f(\cdot)$ appropriately, that is growing fast enough but not too fast, we satisfy these three conditions:

- All other elements of $S(N)$, that is, those larger than $f(n)/6$, will be preserved and found in $S^*(N)$. Those less than $f(n)/6$ are all lost.
- Any element not belonging to $S(N)$ won't be found in $S^*(N)$ either; in other words, my procedure, if $f(\cdot)$ is chosen correctly, won't add numbers that should not be there. If $f(N)$ does not grow fast enough, say $f(N)=\sqrt{N}$, this condition won't be met.
- The vast majority of elements of $S(N)$ are also in $S^*(N)$. This will become clear later in this discussion. If $f(N)$ is growing too fast, say $f(N) = 6N$, then the set $S^*(N)$ is always empty, and we want to avoid that; we actually want it to grow infinitely if possible (that is, if there are infinitely many twin primes) as $N$ increases.

**My question**

Does the function $f(N)=6\sqrt{N}$ satisfy the requirements? This may be a simple question for mathematicians familiar with sieve-like algorithms.

Note: Arguments very similar to mine were used [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07975). That paper starts nicely with convincing arguments, unfortunately, the author claimed (in the second half of his paper) to have proved the Twin Prime Conjecture (TPC) with elementary methods, but nobody thinks the proof is correct. In the next section, I make a deep dive into the very heart of TPC, revealing (I think) original observations I made as a non-mathematician (but as a PhD expert in probability and pattern recognition), and at the same time acknowledging that I am much further away than I thought to proving TPC. My discovery highlights some mysterious behavior of functions that I hope some mathematicians can leverage to gain better understanding of TPC, and possibly prove it. The patterns observed are so strong regardless of $N$, and so smooth, I have a hard time thinking it can not lead to a proof of TPC. Yet, this is really hard unproven stuff, and entirely beyond my capability to bring this to a final proof.

**Background**

Let $M=f(N)$. The optimal $M$ is $M=6\sqrt{N}$ as per above, however, in order to understand the mechanism behind the TPC, one has to look at all possible prime values of $M$ to get a much better understanding.

[image]

Here $N$ is fixed. The above curve corresponds to $N=2000$. The X-axis represents $M$ (primes only), the Y-axis represents the ratio $R(N, M)$ defined as follows:

- Let $g(N)$ be the number of elements in $S^*(N)$.
- Let $h(N)$ be the natural approximation of $g(N)$. This is the natural, intuitive approximation of $g(N)$, because we are dealing with
  independent congruences since all the modulo $p$ are co-prime, and
  indeed prime. It is defined as the product over primes (keeping in mind
  that $M$ is a function of $N$, and optimal $M$ is $6\sqrt{N}$), as follows: $$h(N)=N\cdot \prod_{5\leq p\leq
     M}\frac{p-2}{p}\sim C\cdot \frac{N}{\log^2 M}.$$
- $R(N, M) = h(N)/g(N)$.

There are a number of critical points on this incredibly smooth curve (smooth given the chaotic distribution of primes), and this is even more true for much larger values of $N$:

- At the beginning, on the left side, $R(N, M)$ is extremely close to
  $1$, an obvious fact that even myself could prove easily.
- Then the curve reaches a peak, barely above $1$. The maximum is
  reached at $M_0=M_0(N)$, and its value is $R_0(N)$.
- Then it is slowly decreasing up to $M_1=M_1(N)=6\sqrt{N}$, the
  optimum $f(N)$, attaining the value $R_1(N)$.
- It continues to smoothly decrease for a long time, up to
  $M_2=M_2(N)\geq N$, attaining the value $R_2(N)$.
- At some point, the curve goes back up again, quite steeply, and it
  reaches a point, around $M_3=M_3(N)=6N$, where it becomes permanently
  infinite.

In order to prove the TPC, we have the following options:

- $R_0(N)$ is a very slowly increasing function of $N$, such that
  $R_0(N)=O(1)$. For instance, $R_0(3068200)\approx 1.14$, barely above $R_0(2000)\approx 1.06$.
- If we can't prove this, then prove that $R_1(N)< R_0(N)$ is a very
  slowly increasing function of $N$, such that $R_1(N)=O(1)$.
- If we can't prove this, then prove that $R_2(N)< R_1(N)$ is a very
  slowly increasing function of $N$, such that $R_2(N)=O(1)$.

**Update**

We all assume that $g(N)=O(N/\log^2 N)$ and we all know for certain that $h(N)=O(N/\log^2 N)$. So assuming $R_0(N)=O(1)$ seems reasonable. However, let's think about a worst case scenario, like there are only a finite number of twin primes. In that case, you would expect that $R_0(N)$ would be asymptotically as high as $O(N/\log ^2 N)$. Now, let's think about a more reasonable scenario. Let's say that there are so few elements in $S^*(N)$ so that $g(N)=O(\log N)$. Of course, intuition tells us that there far more than that. But even if this was the case, you would have $R_0(N)=O(N/\log^3 N)$, and still guarantee that there are infinitely many twin primes. The empirical argument discussed here is that $R_0(N)$ can easily be seen to be order of magnitudes below $O(N/\log^3 N)$, possibly making a proof of TPC less difficult than originally thought.  I will post some updates later on, but at this time, based purely on empirical evidence, the main finding is that $M_0(N)\approx \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: Is PTC the same as TPC?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I will fix it as well as potential other typos.